# Flutter ':path_provider:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' Error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Im having problem in the path provider dependencies in flutter.
I've been trying to find a solution for this for almost 2 day now..
please help me..

[image]

My dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  hive: ^1.4.1+1
  hive_flutter: ^0.3.0+2
  path_provider: ^1.6.5
  http: ^0.12.2
```

My Code (even without code its running the error as long as a add the path provider)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  //Hive.initFlutter();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  //final appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  // Hive.init(appDocDir.path);

  var box = await Hive.openBox('employee');

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(home: Home()),
  );
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this using by doing  flutter pub downgrade in the terminal